# How to find the index of a specific element in a std::array<std::optional<unsigned int>, N>?

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have an array of size 80, `std::array< std::optinal<unsigned int>, 80> myArray` which contains numbers from 0-9.
I would like to get the index of the **first array element** with value `x=5`.

When I do as following,

```
auto it = std::find(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), x);
auto index_of_x =std::distance(myArray, it);
```

I get the following error,

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘distance(std::array< std::optinal<unsigned int>, 80>&, const std::optional<unsigned int>*&)’
   93 |         auto index_of_x =std::distance(myArray, it);
      |                                                   ^
```

What is the issue here? Is it a problem with using std::optional?

Comment: -> `std::distance(std::begin(myArray), it);`

Comment: Looking at function's doc of [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) might be useful to check expected parameters.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you! It solved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

[`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) expects 2 iterators, not a container and an iterator.

Call should be:

```cpp
auto index_of_x = std::distance(std::begin(myArray), it);
```

Answer (score 1):

First parameter to `std::distance` is   iterator pointing to the first element. Try

```
std::distance(myArray.begin(), it);
```